# Why can't I SSH in to my Ubuntu VM anymore?

Tags: ssh, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I have a couple Debian based Linux distributions running on VMware Workstation Player on Windows 10. I used to be able to SSH in to the virtual machine from the host machine from a PowerShell or Ubuntu (WSL) terminal without any problem. But lately I have not been able to do so.

First I start the SSH service on the virtual machine.

```
service ssh start
```

Then I verify that the service is running.

```
service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-26 11:30:42 PDT; 1min 14s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 872 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 898 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9448)
     Memory: 2.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─898 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Jun 26 11:30:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jun 26 11:30:42 ubuntu sshd[898]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jun 26 11:30:42 ubuntu sshd[898]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jun 26 11:30:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I verify the IP address.

```
hostname -I
192.168.75.129

ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:a0:15:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    inet 192.168.75.129/24 brd 192.168.75.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 1714sec preferred_lft 1714sec
    inet6 fe80::98eb:dd0a:da24:92be/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

...but Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux cannot connect.

```
ssh 192.168.75.129
ssh -vvv 192.168.75.129
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.75.129 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.75.129 [192.168.75.129] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.75.129 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh: connect to host 192.168.75.129 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

...and PowerShell times out.

```
ssh -vvv 192.168.75.129
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/me/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.75.129 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.75.129 [192.168.75.129] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001B003450380
debug1: connect to address 192.168.75.129 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.75.129 port 22: Connection timed out
```

NMAP returns the following scans.

```
nmap -Pn -p 22 192.168.75.129
Warning: Nmap may not work correctly on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
For best performance and accuracy, use the native Windows build from https://nmap.org/download.html#windows.
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-26 13:36 CDT
NSOCK ERROR [0.0460s] mksock_bind_device(): Setting of SO_BINDTODEVICE failed (IOD #1): Protocol not available (92)
NSOCK ERROR [0.0470s] mksock_bind_device(): Setting of SO_BINDTODEVICE failed (IOD #2): Protocol not available (92)
NSOCK ERROR [0.0470s] mksock_bind_device(): Setting of SO_BINDTODEVICE failed (IOD #3): Protocol not available (92)
Problem binding to interface , errno: 92
socket_bindtodevice: Protocol not available
Problem binding to interface , errno: 92
socket_bindtodevice: Protocol not available
Nmap scan report for 192.168.75.129
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.09 seconds
```

...and from nmap on Windows.

```
PS C:\Users\me> cd '\Program Files (x86)\nmap'
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\nmap> ./nmap.exe -Pn -p 22 192.168.75.129
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
WARNING: Could not import all necessary Npcap functions. You may need to upgrade to the latest version from https://npcap.org. Resorting to connect() mode -- Nmap may not function completely
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-26 13:36 Central Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for 192.168.75.129
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.17 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If both Windows and WSL cannot connect, then the problem is not with WSL and this is off-topic here.

Comment: If the VMs are running Ubuntu (and not some other Debian-based distro), have you confirmed that the firewall is not blocking access? `sudo ufw status` will let you know what rules are active. If you do not see an `ALLOW` for your SSH port, then you'll need to adjust the settings.

Comment: @matigo , `sudo ufw status` returns `Status: inactive`.

Comment: Just a quick tip -- There's no reason to obfuscate the private IP addresses.  "Private" in this case means they only can operate on the local network anyway.  I'd recommend adding them back in for clarity.  Right now, it's not possible in your question to differentiate between a "192.168" address assigned to the local Windows host, that of the VM, or that of the WSL instance.

Comment: You can add verbosity in both client and server by adding -vvv as an argument to the ssh(d) applications

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds , thanks for the tip. I wasn't totally sure if that presented a risk. In this case, all of the IP addresses are of the virtual machine.

Comment: @rm-rf , I tried that, but I did not get any more output that made sense to me.
ssh: connect to host 192.168.__.__ port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: @JustinBrunkow. It might help, if you add this new information into the original question.

Comment: @rm-rf , I have made your suggested edits to the post. Does that give us enough information? It looks like it may be an issue with the configuration file.

Comment: Based on your updated information I found this: https://superuser.com/a/1113508/1410123

Comment: @rm-rf , I don't have an ~/.ssh/config file in WSL. The problem is also happening in PowerShell and PuTTY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must have been with VMware Workstation 16 Player on the host. I reinstalled VMware Workstation and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

i had your problem, finally i solved it by disabling all vmware network adapters in network and internet setting. so do this:

1. go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections in windows
2. disable all vmware adapters
3. enable them again
4. test your ssh and ping, enjoy it!

Comment: Do you mean "Network and Sharing Center" then "Change adapter settings" in the Control Panel? If so, I don't see anything relating to VMware in there. I'm on Windows 10 21H1 and VMware Player 16.1.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Open window setting:

1. Click Network _& Internet.
2. Select change network options.
3. Disable any VMware network Adapter and Enable them again.

If you don't see anything related to the VMware, I suggest you remove and install your VMware again.